# Possible to Resume Other Users' Flow Interviews?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

### Background

I'm trying to allow non-system administrator users to resume Flow interviews by other users.

### Approach

I thought this would be possible using a [custom Aura component](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_pause_cmp_record.htm&type=5) that allows you to display paused Flow interviews by record (instead of per user).

Please open the hyperlinked URL above to see the source code.

### Problem

The paused Flow interviews appear for the user that paused them, but not for other non-system administrator users.

System administrator users are able to see all paused Flow interviews for the record:

[image]

Non-system administrator users are only able to see the Flow interviews which they paused for the record:

[image]

### Question

Is there a way to allow non-system administrator users resume Flow interviews that have been paused by other users?

Thanks in advance.